The relationship between QEC decoding error and capacity
Consider a fixed qubit channel $\mathcal{N}$ and some QECC that prepares a logical state $|\psi_L\rangle$ of $k$ logical qubits using $n$ physical qubits. After transmitting data through the channels, the probability of correctly decoding (and thus recovering $|\psi_L\rangle$ at the output of the decoder) is $p_{err}$ - assume operations are implemented perfectly.
Assume that I have some kind of scalable QECC scheme, so that I can express $p_{err}$ as a funtion of $n$ and $k$.
My question is, what does the tuple $(n, \frac{k}{n}, p_{err})$ tell us about any sort of capacity of the channel $\mathcal{N}$?

My thoughts so far:

This setup implies $\frac{1}{2} \lVert \psi_L - \mathcal{D} \circ \mathcal{N}^{\otimes n} \circ \mathcal{E}(\psi_L)\rVert_1 \leq p_{err}$, so the tuple does describe a code with rate $Q=k/n$ and error $\epsilon=p_{err}$ (using definitions/notation from Wilde's textbook)
But this doesn't seem to actually tell us about the quantum capacity of the channel, since we have no way of taking the error to zero in general
The closest I got was using some ideas from (Tomamichel et al, 2015), that $(n, k/n, p_{err})$ gives a lower bound for the boundary of an achievable region of rates $\hat{R}_\mathcal{N}(n, p_{err}) := \max \{R: (n, R, p_{err})\text{ is achievable}\}$ (where "achievable" just means that tuple describes a code).

I would like to know if (3) is the strongest statement we can make about $\mathcal{N}$ in this scenario, or if there are other capacities that I missed that are bounded once we achieve this tuple.

How do you relate ratio and channel capacity?

Roughly, quantum capacity is the largest ratio $k/n$ found among codes that can transmit states arbitrarily well through $\mathcal{N}^{\otimes n}$, given large enough $n$
